# React Router Nested Routing with Search Params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In nested React routing with search params, when I am on /app and after clicking on Link which navigates to /app/user. Navigation is not working.

If I am trying it without nesting, it is working but. But why it is not working when I am nesting it.

Codesandbox: [CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-leftpad-3cy5t5?file=/src/App.js)

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
    <Route path="/app" element={<Main />}>
      <Route path=":user" element={<User />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
  </Routes>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
     <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
        <Route path="/app" element={<Main />} />
        <Route path="/app/:user" element={<User />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
      </Routes>
```

---

If you want the `User.js` component to be nested, you need to add `Outlet` in `Main.js`

```
import { Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Main Page</p>
      <Link to="/app/ashish">Click to go to user page</Link>

      <Outlet/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @buga
Its working. My question is why it is not working, when nesting is there.

Comment: @AshishGahlot you need to add `Outlet` for it to be nested. I edited my answer to showcase.